# How to persist value between different executions of background process in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, background-process

I have a periodic task that runs every one hour. First time this task runs, it will generate some value. I need to access this value when the task runs the next time. How can I achieve this and what is the best option?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to save the data in the [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402541%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

Here's a [quick start guide](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/quickstarts/Isolated_Storage) to get you going.

The basics for saving:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
// txtInput is a TextBox defined in XAML.
if (!settings.Contains("userData"))
{
settings.Add("userData", txtInput.Text);
}
else
{
settings["userData"] = txtInput.Text;
}
settings.Save();
```

And retrieving:

```
if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("userData"))
{
txtDisplay.Text +=
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["userData"] as string;
}
```